# How can i get data from Text File like this

Tags: java, file, io, frame

Hey guys i'm doing a little program which will be different like this,but now i'm working this.If you run this program you can login or create an account if you don't have,and it will be saved in a text file.My problem is i don't know what is the best way to get these variableas("username" , "password").Now i'm using this : if(lines.startsWith(name) && lines.endsWith(pass)) but its not good for me, because i want to get Boolean admin variable which is saved in textfile too. So the question is how can i get these variables (username , password , admin) from the textfile?

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main{

public JTextField text;
public JTextField textt;
public JButton button;
public JButton buttons;
public JFrame frame;
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
final JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
public Boolean loggedin = false;
public Boolean admin = false;
public Main(){

    GUISETUP();
    MenuCreates();
    CheckLogin();
}


public void GUISETUP(){

    frame = new JFrame("MyFileCreator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(null);

    text = new JTextField();
    text.setSize(300,50);
    text.setLocation(0, 100);

    textt = new JTextField();
    textt.setSize(300,50);
    textt.setLocation(0, 50);

    button = new JButton("Create Account");
    button.setSize(300, 50);
    button.setLocation(0, 150);

    buttons = new JButton("Login");
    buttons.setSize(300, 50);
    buttons.setLocation(0, 200);



    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            writetofile();
        }
    });

    buttons.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            LogIn();
            CheckLogin();
        }
    });


    p.add(button);
    p.add(text);
    p.add(textt);
    p.add(buttons);

    frame.setContentPane(p);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void CheckLogin(){

    if(loggedin.equals(true)){
        menuBar.setVisible(true);
        button.setVisible(false);
        buttons.setVisible(false);
        text.setVisible(false);
        textt.setVisible(false);
    }else{
        menuBar.setVisible(false);
    }

}


public void MenuCreates(){

    final JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

    menuBar.add(fileMenu);


    JMenuItem newAction = new JMenuItem("New");
    JMenuItem openAction = new JMenuItem("Open");

    fileMenu.add(newAction);
    fileMenu.add(openAction);


    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);


    newAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            FileCretor();
        }
    });

    openAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\bazsi\\Desktop"));
            fc.setDialogTitle("Choose your File");
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            if (fc.showOpenDialog(buttons) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                //System.out.println(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(fc.getSelectedFile());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"You didnt choosed any file!","Information",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
    });
}


public void FileCretor(){

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("info.jpg");

    String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Choose your File name!");
    File f = new File(answer + ".txt");
    boolean bool = false;
    if( f.exists()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Error " + answer + " .txt  \nAlready Existing!","Insane Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }else if(answer.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Error" + "\n Type in the file name!","Insane Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }else{

        try{
        bool = f.createNewFile();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,answer + ".txt" + "\nSuccesfully created!","Information",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icon);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public void LogIn(){

    String name;
    String pass;

    try {

        String lines;

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("Accounts.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        name = textt.getText();
        pass = text.getText();

        while((lines = br.readLine()) != null){
            if(lines.startsWith(name) && lines.endsWith(pass)){
                loggedin = true;
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Error" + "\n Wrong Username or Password!","Insane Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void ReadFromFile(){

}

public void writetofile(){

    try{

        String lines;

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("Accounts.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Accounts.txt",true);
        BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(out);

        String username = textt.getText();
        String password = text.getText();

        while((lines = br.readLine()) != null){
            if(lines.startsWith(username)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Error" + "\n This Account is Already Existing!","Insane Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                bf.write(username + " # " + " " + admin  +" " + password);
                bf.newLine();
            }
        }

        textt.setText("");
        text.setText("");

        bf.close();

    }catch(IOException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Error While Try to Write int the File");
    }

}

public void readfromfile(){

}

public static void main (String [] args){
    Main m = new Main ();
}

}
```

Comment: use trim() method whenever you are writing in a file. I have posted answer please mark correct if you find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your code. While writing in file you can separate data using "#" and when you fetch again you can split and check the same. You should ignore starts with because user-name can be john and johnyDepp they both are same according to your logic. Also return admin value to true or false in file.

When you write in file.

```
bf.write(username + "#" + admin + "#" + password);
```

When you read from file.

```
      while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String split[] = lines.split("#");
                    String userName = split[0];
                    Boolean admin = null;
                    if (split[1].trim().length() != 0) {
                        try {
                            admin = Boolean.parseBoolean(split[1]);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }
                    }
                    String password = split[2];

                    if(userName.equals(userN) && password.equals(passW)){
                        if(admin != null && admin){
                            System.out.println("He is a Admin");
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Normal Guy"); 
                        }
                    }
                }
```

**Modified :** here if you do not have much users than you can add same record but an additional field timestamps will be added to make sure which record is updated. here I didn't check the timestamps for most updated ones because I am assuming lowest record in file will be updated.

```
private static String SEPARATOR = "#";

    // Add Null pointer check
    private static void readFromFile(String username, String password) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        String finalCred = null;
        try {
            String line = null;
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_NAME));
            username = username.trim();
            password = password.trim();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String split[] = line.split(SEPARATOR);
                if (username.equals(split[0]) && password.equals(split[1])) {
                    finalCred = line;
                }
            }
            String split[] = finalCred.split(SEPARATOR);
            if (username.equals(split[0]) && password.equals(split[1])) {
                Boolean admin = Boolean.parseBoolean(split[2]);
                if (admin) {
                    System.out.println("User is admin");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not admin");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void writeInFile(String username, String password, Boolean admin) {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
        try {
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILE_NAME,true));
            admin = (admin == null ? false : true);
            username = username.trim();
            password = password.trim();
            bufferedWriter.write(username + SEPARATOR + password + SEPARATOR + admin + SEPARATOR + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+"\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now i have an another problem. All account is just normal guy...i can make admin...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? You mean to say you want to make admin a normal guy or normal guy a admin?

Comment: @BalázsSzmetana I have modified my answer but there will are limitations that you should have more data because that time it will become bottleneck. You have to do some cleanup activity when you do not have traffic. Please mark correct and upvote if I have solved your problem.